# Detecting mobile phones vs tablets?

Tags: web, mobile

I need to create a mobile version of a website (think [m.cnn.com](http://m.cnn.com)).  Is there a way to detect if a device is a mobile phone vs a mobile tablet (e.g. iPad, Xoom, etc.)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper tactic isn't to detect the device but rather to detect the capabilities. What you care about is that the client is 1024x768 or 800x480 or supports HTML5. If you get into the game of device detection you will lose -- what happens when someone invents the next fancy shiny new iThing?

Comment: Keep in mind that you also care about whether the user is using a mouse, a touchscreen, or whatever the heck Blackberry uses as a cursor

Comment: You also may have a requirement to provide content specific to a particular device, in which case only going by capabilities won't cut it.

Comment: Yes, and that would be a different case than the OP asked.

Comment: It's about pixel density: an iPhone supports 980px wide but normal people can't read it.

Answer (score 1):

Your question should probably be moved to stackoverflow.com, and you should add some additional details about what technologies you are using.

To answer your question, if you happen to be on the .NET side of the world, you could look into using something like [51degrees.codeplex.com](http://51degrees.codeplex.com/).

Comment: The programming vs stackoverflow confuses me.  I thought stackoverflow was for "code already written" (to quote [Jeff Atwood](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/introducing-programmers-stackexchange-com/)).